# O notation of a Loop

Tags: algorithm, performance, notation

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) { 
      O(1);
   }
}
```

here the func is `n * (n+1) / 2` but what if the outerloop condition is `i < log(n)`? I have problems with loops that relates on each other.

Comment: If you replace `n` with something else, just replace every `n` in `n * (n+1) / 2` with the same thing. This seems to come down to a lack of understanding of basic algebra (or a temporary mental lapse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to count the total number of iterations:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + .. + n - 1 = n * (n - 1) / 2
```

as you correctly inferred. When you replace `n` with `log(n)`, just do the same in the final formula, which then becomes `log(n) * (log(n)+1) / 2`, or in Big-O notation, `O((log(n))^2)`.

Comment: `1 + 2 + 3 + .. + n = n * (n+1) / 2`, not `1 + 2 + 3 + .. + n - 1`.

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre Of course, very stupid mistake. Tnx.

Answer (score 2):

If the condition of the outer loop is changed to `i < log(n)` then the overall complexity of the nested two-loop construct changes from O(n<sup>2</sup>) to O(log(n)<sup>2</sup>)

You can show this with a simple substitution `k = log(n)`, because the complexity of the loop in terms of `k` is O(k<sup>2</sup>). Reversing the substitution yields O(log(n)<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

For nested for loops (when using the O notation, ofc) you can multiply the worst-case scenario of all of them. If the first loop goes to x and you have a nested loop going to i (i being at worst-case x) then you have a run-time complexity of O(x^2)